# How to display data from a entity declared as icollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a view that I want to select data from another entity, but this entity was declared as Icollection.

The model generated by EF:

```
 namespace SINCO_MVC.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class SINCO_CONCESSAO
{
    public SINCO_CONCESSAO()
    {
     this.SINCO_LEI_AUTORIZATIVA = new HashSet<SINCO_LEI_AUTORIZATIVA>();
     }

    public virtual ICollection<SINCO_LEI_AUTORIZATIVA> SINCO_LEI_AUTORIZATIVA { get; set; }
}
}
```

My index:

```
   [Authorize(Roles = "ADMINISTRADOR")]
    public ActionResult IndexConcessaoLeiAut()
    {
          return View("IndexConcessaoLeiAut", db.SINCO_CONCESSAO.Include(s => s.SINCO_LEI_AUTORIZATIVA).ToList());
    }
```

The sinco_lei_autorizativa model:

```
 namespace SINCO_MVC.Models
 {
     [MetadataType(typeof(SincoLeiAutorizativaMetaData))]
     public partial class SINCO_LEI_AUTORIZATIVA
     {
     }

public class SincoLeiAutorizativaMetaData 
{
    [Display(Name="ID: ")]
    public int IDLEIAUTORIZATIVA { get; set; }

   }
 }
```

My view:

```
 <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IDCONCESSAO) %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SINCO_LEI_AUTORIZATIVA.? ) %>

       </td>
  </tr>
 <% } %>
 </table>
```

I want to select the IDLEIAUTORIZATIVA that is a item of SINCO_LEI_AUTORIZATIVA. When the entity is not declared as a Icollection, I just call the IDLEIAUTORIZATIVA in the DisplayFor. But this is not working, the IDLEIAUTORIZATIVA isn't recognized.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Add a nested `foreach(subItem in item.SINCO_LEI_AUTORIZATIVA) ... DisplayFor(sla => sla.IDLEIAUTORIZATIVA)`

Comment: If you have a collection, you have to iterate over it to access the properties on the instances inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the previous answers I could resolve the issue as follows.

View:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
<tr>
    <td>
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IDCONCESSAO) %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <% foreach (var subitem in item.SINCO_LEI_AUTORIZATIVA)
           { %>

           <%: Html.DisplayFor(sla => subitem.IDLEIAUTORIZATIVA) %>
        <% } %>
    </td>
   <td>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Controller:

```
    var idLei = db.SINCO_LEI_AUTORIZATIVA.Select(t => t.IDLEIAUTORIZATIVA).ToList();

    var result = db.SINCO_CONCESSAO.Include(s => s.SINCO_LEI_AUTORIZATIVA).Where(s => s.SINCO_LEI_AUTORIZATIVA.Any(v => idLei.Contains(v.IDLEIAUTORIZATIVA))).ToList();

    return View(result.ToList());
```

Thanks for the help!!